# get scala worksheet file directory

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

So I want read a image file in scala worksheet but I don't want use absolute path so others no need to change the code before run, how can I achieve that? the following method return the IDE path, not my project path.

the image file and the worksheet file are in same directory

```
val path = File(".").toAbsolute //D:\app\idea2016\bin\
System.getProperty("user.dir")  //D:\app\idea2016\bin\
```

Comment: Why not use `object` with `main` method?

Comment: Provide an optional parameter to supply the path necessary.